# Radeon RX 570 not rendering correctly using Eevee [Linux (Ubuntu), AMD]

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, error, opengl, artifacts

Recently got my GPU setup, and after a bit of trial and error, I was able to get it to work with everything, until I decided just a bit ago to use EEVEE in blender instead of cycles; I was presented with some serious issues doing it:
[image: EEVEE Susan monkey]

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04, OpenGL v:4.5.14756 Core Profile Context 20.40, OpenCL 1.2(2.1?) AMD-APP (3180.7), on a Radeon RX 570 GPU. Drivers are Pro 20.40.
My command when installing the drivers was `./amdgpu-pro-install --pro --opencl=pal,legacy,rocm`

I'm not sure how to fix this nor what is even causing it and I'd like to find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it by manually installing the bundled packages with the term `opencl-*_amd64.deb`, using dpkg to correctly install their dependencies as needed. This [solution](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/install-amd-opencl-on-pop-os-some-ubuntu-derivates/13458) from the devtalk may also work and is probably easier, but I didn't try it.